# How to move caret to end of file without End key

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using a Mac, and I want to move the cursor to the last line of file without using `Home`, `End`, or `Page Down` keys.

Any idea?

I've tried "scroll to bottom" keymap but that only moves the scroll, not the caret.

Comment: You can assign any other/custom shortcut to `Move Caret to Text End` action in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`

Comment: you could use vim plugin then `g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `⌘A, →`.

But it's better to assign shortcut as @LazyOne suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There's a reserved Editor Action for this and it's named `Move Caret to Text End`. You can find this in the Preferences window (*Preferences -> Keymap -> Editor Actions*). The counterpart of this action is `Move Caret to Text Bottom`, in case anyone is interested.

In Mac, native text editors come with shortcuts `cmd+up` and `cmd+down` out of the box to easily jump to the top or the bottom of the page (*along with the caret*). You'd mostly want to adopt the same shortcuts on your PHPStorm IDE to make page navigation more seamless.